# How to use addin from web in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I downloaded a tool and installed it in the ArcGIS, which can allow me split by attribute very easily and quickly. I wonder how I can use it as the built-in tools of the ArcGIS, so that I can write python code to use it as I need? For example, we can use Clip as writing arcpy.Clip_Managerment. I want to have a similar way of writing code for the split by attribute tool installed in the ArcGIS.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 Advanced License.
The tool website is http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html.
The following picture shows the tool I installed in the ArcGIS.
[image]

Comment: If it's a python addin and you have permission to modify/access the source code, you could access the source and use it within your code.  Please check for permission first

Comment: @Midavalo it's not a python add-in, it's .NET. I downloaded it and the add-in contains a .dll

Comment: OK In that case I don't believe it can be done directly without the publisher of the tool making a geoprocessing tool available for access through arcpy.  I imagine you could determine what it does and replicate the behaviour in your own arcpy script

Comment: You may find [this article about calling DLLs from a script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/calling-a-dll-from-a-script-tool.htm) and another one [about deploying third party DLLs into addin](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63509) useful. I was also wondering why don't you develop a similar python script to do the same job?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124232/115 may be useful to you.

Comment: I agree with @Midavalo, if it is a .Net AddIn then it is not exposed to the geo-processing framework and you won't be able to call it from within a python script. AddIns are for interacting with the application framework (in this case clicking on a button in a toolbar). I think PolyGeo has provided the best solution with his link.

Comment: I have code for the same process, but the runtime is much greater than that of the addin. I will find another way. Thanks all.